# Chef shell script interaction

Tags: ruby, shell, chef-infra

I have a recipe in Chef that uses `execute` commands to connect to a repository and install a daemon, then configure and start it.

When`apt-get install` runs, it requires user confirmation (Y/N input) to continue after it determines how much space is needed. How can this be done programatically in Chef?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass `--yes` to `apt-get install` and it won't prompt interactively.  Chef also has higher-level package abstraction libraries that can do this for you.

```
package 'foo' do
    action :install
end
```

Comment: Thanks - that solves the confirmation issue, but before the installer finishes it also asks if the user wants to register the machine with the provider. Is there a general way to give an answer to all prompts?

Comment: That sounds like a prompt your package in particular is creating (perhaps via one of its pre/post scripts).  What specific package are you installing?  Have you looked at its man page or documentation?  And can you clarify what you mean by registering with a provider?

Comment: It is a prompt specific to the package - it asks if it is to register the machine with the user's account on a company's website. Would there any way to bypass it by answering no?

Comment: Look at the docs for that package for a command line argument or other way to force non-interactive mode.  Something simple like doing `echo yes | apt-get install --yes mypackage` may also work if the script is just reading from stdin.

Comment: It does use stdin - using `echo` worked perfectly. Thank you!